# Hurricane Sandy

Tags: recording, nature, hurricane

Anyone on the east coast trying to record this behemoth? Could be a once in a lifetime opportunity. Heavy waves and storm surge could be good but you'll have to use extreme caution. Or, you could attach some contact mics to your walls and windows…or you could open one of those windows *just a little bit* and record some gnarly whistling and moaning…or…or…or…

Stay safe out there, East coasters!

Comment: For interest sake, the servers were down from hurricane Sandy...  

Answer (score 8):

I'm stuck in San Francisco, but my wife commanded me to walk her through setting up my rig over Skype. Can't wait to hear what she records for me!

**UPDATE:** She chickened out :p

Comment: Good thing you wifed her. She's a keeper!!!

Answer (score 7):

I put up a bunch of recordings yesterday if you want to check some of them out. It was quite a  night. http://sepulchra.com/blog/?p=1959

Answer (score 5):

Michael Raphael (Rabbit Ears Audio) has been recording some stuff.  He's even posted sounds already:

http://soundcloud.com/sepulchra/wind-hurricane-sandy-short

He also posted some pics of his DPA 4060's attached to his windows.

Answer (score 2):

I got some good wind sounds from my area in North Carolina.  But I am rather far inland so I cant get any of the cool rain and waves you asked about.

Comment: will swap you some of those sounds for this

http://soundcloud.com/kurt_human/sets/machines-in-a-bullet-factory/

Answer (score 2):

got quite a bit from an apartment in Green Point.. one's up online here:

http://soundcloud.com/jameshayday/hurricane-sandy-green-point

Answer (score 1):

I live in central Maine and while we were not hit with the bulk of the storm, I was able to get some super consistant heavy rain recordings as well as some fun internal bits. Some of my best from last week are a storm gutter inside the building I work in.

Comment: @Scott Leland, I grew up near Bangor. Where are you?

Comment: I grew up in Kittery but am currently working in Farmington until January. I plan on moving to Portland around that time!